# Creating UIImages from NSArray that was created in Android (and the reverse)

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, uiimage, android-bitmap

I am trying to share images between an android client and an iOS client (through a server).
The android code already exists, and I prefer not to alter it if possible. Therefore, this is an iOS programming question (specifically, objective-C).

In the existing java code, bitmap images are compressed with png and converted to byteArrays with the following sample code:

```
public void setPic(Bitmap bitmapPic){
   ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   bitmapPic.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
   this.pic = stream.toByteArray();
}
```

The reverse (byteArray to bitmap) is done in android via:

```
BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(picArray, 0, picArray.length);
```

After retrieving these byteArrays as NSCFArrays of NSCFNumbers (values -128 to 128) in iOS, I would like to convert them to UIImage. Likewise, I would like to produce similar NSArrays from UIImages in iOs to send back to the android application.

Here is my attempt from previous googling to extract the NSArray imageArray. It yields a UIImage with non-sense pixels:

```
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace=CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef bitmapContext=CGBitmapContextCreate((__bridge void * _Nullable)(imageArray), 50, 50, 8, 4*50, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault| kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
CGImageRef cgImage=CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmapContext);
CGContextRelease(bitmapContext);
UIImage * newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];
```

I am not including the server talk code because I don't think that's the issue. Could provide more info if needed.

Comment: When you retrieve the bytes from the server, you have an `NSData` object with the server's response.  Assuming the server isn't sending extra data, you can take that response and use it directly to create a `UIImage` using `imageWithData:`.

Comment: Thanks, I am not receiving an NSData object from the server